# How to display Success message after clicking Save in HTML page

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an html form containing this code which runs on IIS:

```
<form action="http://server1/data.asp" method="POST">
Your Name: <input name="name" type="text">
<input value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

After user submits this form it runs the code in data.asp which displays a Success message with code to write to a text file (file1.txt):

```
Success!
<%
Dim fso
Dim tst

Set fso=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tst = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\data\file1.txt", 8, true)

tst.writeline "Name = " & Request.Form("name")
tst.writeline "" & Request.Form("")

tst.close
Set tst = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
%>
```

This works but it just shows a page with Success! and stays there. What I'd really like is:

After user submits the form by clicking **Save** I'd like a little message box that says "Success" and remain on the same html page or go to a url I specify within the code.

I don't want to use Java or 3rd party extensions. This is an HTML page that runs the data.asp page on submit and I'd like it to stay that way if possible.

So how would I modify the html and/or data.asp page to do this?

Comment: This ASP code, not ASP.NET you are aware of that? If you create a new project, I highly recommand to move to ASP.NET MVC, more recent, more powerfull and a better future than ASP.

Comment: ASP and ASP.NET is very new to me. I don't even know the difference. Regardless, I have a data.asp file and as you say it's ASP code. So again, where do I put your code so that it shows Success message alert on submit and to make it simple just stay on the same form page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by adding an extra page to the mix (redir2form.asp):

**in data.asp:**

```
<%
Dim fso
Dim tst

Set fso=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tst = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\data\file1.txt", 8, true)

tst.writeline "Name = " & Request.Form("name")
tst.writeline "" & Request.Form("")

tst.close
Set tst = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
%>
Response.Redirect "http://server1/redir2form.asp"
```

**in redir2form.asp:**

```
<%
response.write ("<script>alert('Success!');</script>")
%>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://server1/index.htm" />
```

Index.htm has the form action going to the data.asp page.

Not as neat as it could be but that's how I got it to work. After a user submits the form he gets the "Success!" message box and once they click OK they're redirected back to the form page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Response.Redirect "https://www.yoursite.com/thankyou.asp"
```

Comment: That'd just take me to another page which basically is going to result in the same problem as I already have...it'll just display the thankyou.html page that says Success and not go back to the form page (index.html). So actually I'd prefer it just display a Success message alert, submit it in the background to the file1.txt file and stay on the form page (index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning "Success!" as your response content you can return the form content you have above, this way you can use the same file for the GET and POST methods, with an condition on your asp logic to execute only on POST requests and return a success alert when the code is excuted successfully.

```
<form action="http://server1/index.asp" method="POST">
Your Name: <input name="name" type="text">
<input value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
<%

If (Request.Method = "POST") Then
    Dim fso
    Dim tst

    Set fso=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set tst = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\data\file1.txt", 8, true)

    tst.writeline "Name = " & Request.Form("name")
    tst.writeline "" & Request.Form("")

    tst.close
    Set tst = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    response.write ("<script>alert('Success!');</script>")

End If
%>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear on where I put your code. Do I put all your code in the data.asp file and don't change anything in my index.html file? If I do I get an error after clicking Submit. I don't think it likes the If (Request.Method = "POST")... in the data.asp file. If I put it in all in the index.html file then what do I put in the data.asp file?

Comment: What I mean is that you can replace your index.html file (which is your GET response) with a new asp file including the content of index.html as well as the asp code for writing to the text file. That way you can use the same file (index.asp) for your GET method when you just load the page as well as for your POST method when you submit the form.

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error occurred on the server when processing the url. I renamed the html file to asp and added the above code but maybe I'm not doing something right as the page actually has two form actions one after the other (on the same page) where the user can fill out the one form and press Save or fill out the other form and press Save so I'm guessing this has something to do with my issue. Although I tried deleting the 2nd form temporarily and I still get an error. Do I add the <% .. %> code before /html or after and if after will it work for both forms?

Comment: I just realized since it's an .asp page now there should probably be no <html> or </html> but I still get the same error. And trying your code on a totally new asp page I get the same error too. The MS link I get for this error refers to missing the ISAP Extension in my IIS role but it is installed. Do I need the ASP.net role too? I only have the ASP role installed.

Comment: Does anyone else have any other suggestions? All I'm trying to do is display a Success! message after the user submits a form (while still on the form page - or it can redirect back to the form page after displaying the Success! message). I'm sure it's not hard for someone experienced in writing html/asp pages for IIS.